# How to remove a newline character in a particular line through perl?

Tags: regular-expression, perl

I want to remove a newline character in a particular line through perl one-liner command.

**Input:**

```
1407233497,1407233514,bar
1407233498,1407233515,foo
mingstats&fmt=n
1407233499,1407233516,foobar
```

**Expected output:**

```
1407233497,1407233514,bar
1407233498,1407233515,foomingstats&fmt=n
1407233499,1407233516,foobar
```

**What i tried so far?**

This regex `\n(?!\d+,\d+)` matches exactly the newline that i want to remove. But i don't know how to implement it through perl one-liner command. I tried,

```
perl -pe 's/\n(?!\d+,\d+)//g' file
```

But it removes all the newline characters in that file and finally print the below in a single line,

```
1407233497,1407233514,bar1407233498,1407233515,foomingstats&fmt=n1407233499,1407233516,foobar
```

<sub>I will be so happy if the  perl one-liner command uses above regex...</sub>

Comment: The (nice) quote you have on your home page doesn't come from Mark Twain. It is dirived from text in the song "Come from the heart" written by [Leigh & Clark](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Come_from_the_Heart)

Comment: Good to Know. I'll change it soon..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try:

```
$ perl -00pe 's/\n(?!\d+,\d+)//g' file
1407233497,1407233514,bar
1407233498,1407233515,foomingstats&fmt=n
1407233499,1407233516,foobar
```

`perl` read file line by line by default with `-p` option, so your regex can not work.

`-00` option turns paragraph slurp mode on, your regex now can work on multiline.

From perldoc perlrun:

> -0[octal/hexadecimal]
>
> specifies the input record separator ($/ ) as an octal or hexadecimal
>   number. If there are no digits, the null character is the separator.
>   Other switches may precede or follow the digits. For example, if you
>   have a version of find which can print filenames terminated by the
>   null character.
>
> ...
>
> The special value 00 will cause Perl to slurp files in paragraph mode.
>   Any value 0400 or above will cause Perl to slurp files whole, but by
>   convention the value 0777 is the one normally used for this purpose

Comment: this also works `perl -0007 -pe 's/\n(?!\d+,\d+)//' file`. May i know what is `-0007` and `-p00e`?

Comment: and also what is `paragraph slurp mode`?

Comment: +1 nice, may i know how to use dotall modifier `(?s)` in perl oneliner command?

Comment: get into [here](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/26/unix-and-linux) if you have time..

Answer (score 2):

```
perl -pe 'print "\n" if $c and !/^(?!\d+,\d+)/; $c=chomp; END{print "\n" if $c}' file_name
```

Comment: +1 for your effort.. May i know what is `chomp` , `$c` ?

Comment: `chomp` removes end of line mark.  `chomp` without parameters operated on `$_`. `chomp` returns number of removed characters. `$c` variable in the above code stores information if previous line contained end of line mark.